# How to do server rendering for react router version 4?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router-v4

Since I learn the server rendering from Pro MERN Stack which Vasan is the author.
There is a server rendering lesson, he use react-router for server rendering.
If I am going to use react router version 4, where can I find the tutorial or any resources to map convert the following code to react router version 4???, Please help. T_T

renderedPageRouter.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { match, RouterContext } from 'react-router';

import Router from 'express';

import template from './template.js';
import routes from '../src/Routes.jsx';
import ContextWrapper from '../src/ContextWrapper.jsx';

const renderedPageRouter = new Router();

renderedPageRouter.get('*', (req, res) => {
  match({ routes, location: req.url }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    if (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error.message);
    } else if (redirectLocation) {
      res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
    } else if (renderProps) {
      const componentsWithData = renderProps.components.filter(c => c.dataFetcher);
      const dataFetchers = componentsWithData.map(c => c.dataFetcher({
        params: renderProps.params, location: renderProps.location,
        urlBase: 'http://localhost:3000', cookie: req.headers.cookie,
      }));
      Promise.all(dataFetchers).then((dataList) => {
        let initialState = {};
        dataList.forEach((namedData) => {
          initialState = Object.assign(initialState, namedData);
        });
        const html = renderToString(
          <ContextWrapper initialState={initialState} >
            <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
          </ContextWrapper>
        );
        res.status(200).send(template(html, initialState));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(`Error rendering to string: ${err}`);
      });
    } else {
      res.status(404).send('Not found');
    }
  });
});

export default renderedPageRouter;
```

Comment: Have you looked at the React Router docs? They have a page on server rendering for v4: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/server-rendering

Comment: Hi Joe, Thank you very much for your response, but I'm very new to React programming, so I think I should take some tutorials.